# Return true - submitting an online form with Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function FormSubmit(formid) {

this.initialize = function(formid) {
    this.formid = formid;
    $(formid).observe('submit', this.send);
}


this.send = function() {
    alert('sending '+this.formid)
    this.formid.onSubmit = true;
}

this.initialize(formid); 
} 

var form = new FormSubmit('donate_form');


<form method="post" 
action="https://mysite.com/form_submit" 
onsubmit="return false;" id="donate_form">
```

How can I make the above code, submit the form?
The event works, but the form doesn't submit.

Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
this.formid.onSubmit = true;
```

to

```
this.formid.submit();
```

**Update**

Whoops...forgot to double check the Javascript framework you were using. It looks like you're using Prototype. Please correct me if I'm wrong. In that case, instead of

```
this.formid.onSubmit = true;
```

you could try just

```
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

use document.forms[0].submit();

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
document.getElementById('donate_form').submit();
```